# Spring security + RestEasy dont deploy builds well deploys to REFLECTION

Tags: spring, spring-security, jboss-eap-7

hey guys I have created a maven project with resteasy lib and I test it and work well called by simple java main project, but I have alot problems to integrate this project with a war project because I have always this kind of error

```
full log error https://pastebin.com/iKNHXJbp

[org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter]: 
    Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: REFLECTION
```

I suspect is a problem with this library com.sun.xml.bind.v2.model.impl. but if someoe can helpme with tips, thanks in advance..

the envioroment 
 - EAP7.1 
 - springsecurity 
 - resteasy

the structure of the situacion
my new resteasy project is used by a custom project, that project is a customcomponent for primefaces, and the custom component is used by the final war project.
[image]

DEPENDENCIES 
 war project dependencies

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- DEPENDECIAS INTERNAS -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- DEPENDENCIAS INTERNAS -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.jersey/jersey-client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.19.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- DEPENDENCIAS SPRING -->
    <!-- Spring Web MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring security core, web, config, aspects, taglibs -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${springsec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${springsec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${springsec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${springsec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${springsec.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Core, Context, Support, beans, test, Web MVC -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ebaysf.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>custom.jasperserver.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>mirecarga-jasper</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>custom.component.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-customComponentPrimefaces</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Please add your dependencies to the question

Answer (score 0):

This looks very much like a version mismatch. Are you sure that all of your Spring jars are the same version?
Do you use Maven or Gradle? Is there a chance it is picking up an older version transitively?

Comment: It's absolutely spring version mismatch because you are using different version spring here: ${spring.version}, ${springsec.version}

Comment: hey,@Thuat Nguyen  meybe you have reason, but I can solve the problem disable all dependencies and proyecy dependencies from war that thier uses jersey how dependency, I'll post the completly answer later